# Get all tags associated with a tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm wondering how to get all the tags within a `Text` widget *at a time*. So let's say this is my contents:

---

*(Assuming each time I put ("tag", text), I mean that **text** has the tag **tag**.)*

> `("keyword", print) ("string", "Hello world!")`
>   `("keyword", print) ("string", "You are"), ("support", raw_input())`

---

Now let's say that this is my code for each tag:

```
self.text.tag_config('keyword', foreground="orange")
self.text.tag_config('operator', foreground="blue")
self.text.tag_config('number', foreground="red")
self.text.tag_config('string', foreground="red")
self.text.tag_config('support', foreground="blue")
self.text.tag_config('comment', foreground="violet")
self.text.tag_config('error', background="red")
self.text.tag_config('warning', background="yellow")
```

Now, is there any function / constant to get only the tags currently within my string? It would report `['keyword', 'string', 'support']`.

*(Note: mostly I'm just wondering about this because I'm curious. It's not like it's the end of the world if there isn't. :P)*

Notice: the second code block was written in Python and I'm hoping for an answer in Python. :)

Comment: Do you want a list of all tag names associated with a particular `Text` widget?  Or all tags that are currently active within the widget?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [my favorite tkinter reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-methods.html)

> .tag_names(index=None)
>
> If you pass an index argument, this method returns a sequence of all the tag names that are associated with the character after that
> index. If you pass no argument, you get a sequence of all the tag
> names defined in the text widget.

`.tag_ranges(tagName)` lists the indexes where a particular tag is used.

Comment: Cool! And also, I use that reference lots too. :)